# visp_tracker documentation or tutorial

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I would like to perform object localization by tagging different objects in the environment and getting the pixel coordinates of those objects, which I can then convert to my robot coordinate frame using tf. I was looking for a library to do this and came across vision_visp which seems do exactly what I want. I am running ROS Groovy on Ubuntu 12.04 and I have installed ros-groovy-vision-visp. I am able to launch the client, tracker, viewer nodes albeit they don't do anything or die. I was wondering if there is any documentation or tutorial on how to get started using visp or any suggestions that you all can give on what my next step should be.

Essentially, I want to grab an image from the camera which is pointed to an object having either QR code or any one of patterns that ViSP supports and get the pixel coordinates of that from the object_position topic published by the tracker.

Thanks for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/143876/visp_tracker-documentation-or-tutorial/) by [Sudarshan](https://answers.ros.org/users/291/sudarshan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2014-03-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I find the [ROS wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/vision_visp) and the [ViSP page](http://team.inria.fr/lagadic/visp/visp.html) very good and detailed.

vision_visp worked for me out of the box.

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2014-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sudarshan](https://answers.ros.org/users/291/sudarshan/) on 2014-03-25**:
Thanks for your reply. I looked at the ROS wiki page before posting here, but I could only find docs on what  vision_visp does rather than how to go about doing it. Maybe I'm looking at the wrong place? Its great to know that it works out of the box.